# state props overridden by plugin props

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

here is the component contains "react-dropzone" plugin below

```
class Submit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.props.appState.recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes")) || []
    }

    submitForm() {
        debugger //I also get props properly here.
        this.props.appState.recipe.name = this.name.value
        this.props.history.push('/home')
    }

    onImageDrop(files) {
        debugger //props overridden by Dropzone props :( appState is undefined
        this.props.appState.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl = files[0]
    }
    render() {
        return (
         <form onSubmit={() => this.submitForm()}>
            <Dropzone
                multiple={false}
                accept="image/*"
                onDrop={this.onImageDrop}>
                <p>Drop an image or click to select a file to upload.</p>
            </Dropzone>...
        )
    }
}

export default Submit
```

I am able to access mobx props in constructor and form on submit method of form(submitForm()) but if i upload a file to Dropzone and check the props content in "onImageDrop()" function I dont recognaize any of properties. Ok for experienced react developers that makes sense but I couldnt understand why its override my own state props and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding issue. Either prebind `onImageDrop` in constructor (which is preferred way)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)
    this.onImageDrop = this.onImageDrop.bind(this)

    this.props.appState.recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes")) || []
}
```

or use arrow function as you did for `submitForm`

```
render() {
    return (
     <form onSubmit={() => this.submitForm()}>
        <Dropzone
            multiple={false}
            accept="image/*"
            onDrop={files => this.onImageDrop(files)}>
            <p>Drop an image or click to select a file to upload.</p>
        </Dropzone>...
    )
}
```

Comment: Absolutely! Thank man, saved me greatly, I will accept it as soon as its available to

Comment: @TyForHelpDude No problem